# Graphviz sfdp inferior in ubuntu comparing to mac?

Tags: performance, macos, ubuntu, graph, graphviz

```
sfdp -Goverlap=prism -Tsvg grafo.gv > grafo.svg
```

This simple command seams to behave differently in my computer (I have ubuntu 11) comparing to my friend's mac. In my computer it takes something like a minute, while on it's computer it takes less then a second. Our hardware isn't that different in therms of processor (I don't have my graphics card drivers installed thought, but I doubt graphviz uses graphic card to do something)

Also the output files look different- his looks much better (this is his):

[image]

Mine just spreads all the nodes in a enormous area...! And it seams kinda buggy when opening with a svg viewer :/ Sometimes i doesn't even open at all.

I don't understand what might be the cause of this, my version of graphviz is relatively recent.
Here is some eventually useful information:

> dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600) Activated plugin
>   library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6 Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
>   Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6 Using layout:
>   dot:dot_layout Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.so.6 Using
>   render: dot:core Using device: dot:dot:core The plugin configuration
>   file:     /usr/lib/graphviz/config6       was successfully loaded.
>       render    :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
>       layout    :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
>       textlayout    :  textlayout
>       device    :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk
>   vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
>       loadimage :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg

Would be great if you people could help me. Here is the gv file, so you can try to render it yourself:
http://www.2shared.com/file/_vZxHami/grafo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing a more recent version of graphviz. Apparently, the prism layout algorithm was not avaible with the version I had installed. It's weird thought, because may friend had an older version...